# Is it possible to create a Custom Editor for Birthdate that doesn't necessarily override the one for Date?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I want to create a custom editor Content Template for a property on our view model that corresponds to a `Birthdate`, which is really in the database a simple `smalldatetime` object.  I'm hesitant to simply override either the standard `Date` or `DateTime`, because this is a large project and I don't want to force the behavior everywhere.

Is it possible to add either a new DataType to the DataAnnotations collection of `Birthdate`, or are there some tags that I've yet to find so that I can direct that property to use a specified Editor and Display content template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MyModel
{
    [UIHint("BirthDate")]
    public DateTime BornOn { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in Views/Shared/EditorTemplates, create BirthDate.cshtml. The EditorFor will use that editor template instead of the DateTime.cshtml editor template.